# How to bypass class level map-null="false" for a specific field in dozer?

Tags: mapping, dozer

In the mapping below, ObjectB has been set to map-null="false", and I think that means that any null property from ObjectA will not be set to ObjectB.

However, for a certain property only (say propB), I need ObjectA to successfully pass and set ObjectB's property even if it is null.

How do I bypass map-null="false" for this property? or is there any workaround I can do?

Thanks.

```
<mapping wildcard="false">
        <class-a>ObjectA</class-a>
        <class-b map-null="false">ObjectB</class-b>
        <field>
            <a>propA</a>
            <b>childB.propA</b>
        </field>
        <field>
            <a>propB</a>
            <b>childB.propB</b>
        </field>
</mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a workaround by creating a separate dozer mapping between ObjectA and childB. Check the dozer mapping below:

```
<mapping wildcard="false">
        <class-a>ObjectA</class-a>
        <class-b map-null="false">ObjectB</class-b>
        <field>
            <a>propA</a>
            <b>childB.propA</b>
        </field>
        <field>
            <a>this</a>
            <b>childB</b>
        </field>
</mapping>

<mapping wildcard="false">
        <class-a>ObjectA</class-a>
        <class-b>childB</class-b>
        <field>
            <a>propB</a>
            <b>propB</b>
        </field>
</mapping>
```

This way, propB can be null and will be valid because it is in a different mapping.